# Playwright browsers not installed in CI after updating to newer version

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, playwright, ubuntu-20.04

The situation is as follows:
We run e2e Playwright tests based on JS/TS, two of CI pipeline steps are

```
    - script: npm ci
      displayName: 'npm ci'

    - script: sudo npx playwright install --with-deps
      displayName: 'install Playwright dependencies'
```

so we're sure that clean install is performed, and Playwright browsers together with their dependencies are installed on CI Ubuntu 20 agent. To boost performance, installed node.js dependencies and browsers together with their deps are cached.

After updating Playwright from 1.35 to 1.36 an error message is thrown when running CI pipeline:

```
Error: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/playout/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1071/chrome-linux/chrome
```

I find it strange, as chromium version in 1.36 is exactly the same as in 1.35.
I tried to fix the problem with removing both `ms-playwright` folder from `.cache` and `.npm` where npm cache is stored, but that didn't help, and the error persists.

The `install Playwright dependencies` log is below:

```
2023-07-12T12:33:03.6256664Z Installing dependencies...
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8136637Z Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8137613Z Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8138050Z Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8168083Z Hit:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8834264Z Hit:5 https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian all InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:03.8935058Z Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli jammy InRelease
2023-07-12T12:33:04.9499946Z Reading package lists...
2023-07-12T12:33:05.0094412Z Reading package lists...
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1639017Z Building dependency tree...
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1649728Z Reading state information...
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1694958Z fonts-freefont-ttf is already the newest version (20120503-10build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1695310Z fonts-liberation is already the newest version (1:1.07.4-11).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1695512Z gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.20.1-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1695685Z libasound2 is already the newest version (1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1695863Z libatk-bridge2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.38.0-3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696030Z libatk1.0-0 is already the newest version (2.36.0-3build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696198Z libatspi2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.44.0-3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696383Z libcairo-gobject2 is already the newest version (1.16.0-5ubuntu2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696556Z libcairo2 is already the newest version (1.16.0-5ubuntu2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696732Z libdbus-glib-1-2 is already the newest version (0.112-2build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1696854Z libegl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697024Z libenchant-2-2 is already the newest version (2.3.2-1ubuntu2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697138Z libepoxy0 is already the newest version (1.5.10-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697255Z libevdev2 is already the newest version (1.12.1+dfsg-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697432Z libevent-2.1-7 is already the newest version (2.1.12-stable-1build3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697619Z libfontconfig1 is already the newest version (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697733Z libgles2 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1697845Z libglx0 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698010Z libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.20.1-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698202Z libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.20.1-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698386Z libgudev-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1:237-2build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698566Z libhyphen0 is already the newest version (2.8.8-7build2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698677Z libicu70 is already the newest version (70.1-2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1698850Z libjpeg-turbo8 is already the newest version (2.1.2-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1699388Z liblcms2-2 is already the newest version (2.12~rc1-2build2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1699568Z libmanette-0.2-0 is already the newest version (0.2.6-3build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1699742Z libnspr4 is already the newest version (2:4.32-3build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1699868Z libopengl0 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700024Z libopenjp2-7 is already the newest version (2.4.0-6).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700194Z libopus0 is already the newest version (1.3.1-0.1build2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700361Z libpng16-16 is already the newest version (1.6.37-3build5).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700480Z libproxy1v5 is already the newest version (0.4.17-2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700640Z libsecret-1-0 is already the newest version (0.20.5-2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1700805Z libsoup2.4-1 is already the newest version (2.74.2-3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701051Z libwoff1 is already the newest version (1.0.2-1build4).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701223Z libxcb-shm0 is already the newest version (1.14-3ubuntu3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701387Z libxcb1 is already the newest version (1.14-3ubuntu3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701571Z libxcomposite1 is already the newest version (1:0.4.5-1build2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701755Z libxcursor1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.0-2build4).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1701945Z libxdamage1 is already the newest version (1:1.1.5-2build2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702124Z libxext6 is already the newest version (2:1.3.4-1build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702257Z libxfixes3 is already the newest version (1:6.0.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702429Z libxi6 is already the newest version (2:1.8-1build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702552Z libxkbcommon0 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702722Z libxrandr2 is already the newest version (2:1.5.2-1build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1702914Z libxrender1 is already the newest version (1:0.9.10-1build4).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1703096Z libxtst6 is already the newest version (2:1.2.3-1build4).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1703290Z xfonts-scalable is already the newest version (1:1.0.3-1.2ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1703481Z fonts-ipafont-gothic is already the newest version (00303-21ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1703669Z fonts-tlwg-loma-otf is already the newest version (1:0.7.3-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1703856Z fonts-unifont is already the newest version (1:14.0.01-1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704029Z fonts-wqy-zenhei is already the newest version (0.9.45-8).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704194Z libffi7 is already the newest version (3.3-5ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704387Z libx264-163 is already the newest version (2:0.163.3060+git5db6aa6-2build1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704578Z xfonts-cyrillic is already the newest version (1:1.0.5).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704764Z fonts-noto-color-emoji is already the newest version (2.038-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1704957Z gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.20.3-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1705142Z libatomic1 is already the newest version (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1705321Z libcups2 is already the newest version (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.4).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1705495Z libdbus-1-3 is already the newest version (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1705678Z libdrm2 is already the newest version (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1705858Z libfreetype6 is already the newest version (2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1706141Z libgbm1 is already the newest version (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1706336Z libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1706514Z libglib2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1706697Z libgstreamer1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.20.3-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.1706868Z libgtk-3-0 is already the newest version (3.24.33-1ubuntu2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3357845Z libharfbuzz-icu0 is already the newest version (2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3358209Z libharfbuzz0b is already the newest version (2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3358736Z libnotify4 is already the newest version (0.7.9-3ubuntu5.22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3358947Z libnss3 is already the newest version (2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3359138Z libpango-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3359336Z libpangocairo-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3359523Z libwayland-client0 is already the newest version (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3359716Z libwayland-egl1 is already the newest version (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3359901Z libwayland-server0 is already the newest version (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3360099Z libwebpdemux2 is already the newest version (1.2.2-2ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3360282Z libx11-6 is already the newest version (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3360570Z libx11-xcb1 is already the newest version (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3360765Z libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3360952Z libxslt1.1 is already the newest version (1.1.34-4ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3361145Z ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3361335Z gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version (1.20.3-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3361530Z gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version (1.20.3-0ubuntu1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3361723Z xvfb is already the newest version (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1).
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3361867Z The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3372589Z   libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libopts25 sntp
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3372859Z Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
2023-07-12T12:33:05.3618158Z 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
2023-07-12T12:33:05.4042907Z ##[section]Finishing: install Playwright dependencies
```

As we can see above, browser deps seem to be placed elsewhere, and browsers don't get installed after removing both PW and npm cache.
Is there any other thing I missed trying to make `npx playwright install` install the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, removed `sudo` from `sudo npx playwright install --with-deps`. The `sudo` command executes the preceding command with administrative privileges, which means it uses the root user environment instead of regular user environment.